# Python Langchain "The apply_and_parse method is deprecated, instead pass an output parser directly to LLMChain."

Tags: python, langchain

I'm using langchain to receive a response based on my own data, but it returns the error "The apply_and_parse method is deprecated, instead pass an output parser directly to LLMChain." How can I solve it? Can somebody assist me?

```
def LoadVector():
    global VectorStore   
    VectorStore = FAISS.load_local(Vector_Path, embeddings)

LoadVector()

memory = ConversationBufferMemory(
        memory_key="chat_history", return_messages=True,)  
#retriever = VectorStore.as_retriever()
retriever = VectorStore.as_retriever(search_type="mmr")



qa = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(OpenAI(temperature=0), retriever=retriever, memory=memory,chain_type="map_rerank")
query="what is power app give response in detail"
result = qa({"question": query})
print(result)`


output:




CustomChatBotGPTModel\env\Lib\site-packages\langchain\chains\llm.py:303: UserWarning: The apply_and_parse method is deprecated, instead pass an output parser directly to LLMChain.
  warnings.warn(
{'question': 'what is power app give response in detail', 'chat_history': [HumanMessage(content='what is power app give response in detail', additional_kwargs={}, example=False), AIMessage(content=' Power 
Apps is a low-code platform for building custom business applications. It enables users to create applications from data that can be used across mobile, tablet, and web platforms. It also provides a canvas for users to create applications with a drag-and-drop interface. Power Apps also provides a library of connectors to connect to other services such as Dynamics 365, Office 365, SharePoint, and more.', additional_kwargs={}, example=False)], 'answer': ' Power Apps is a low-code platform for building custom business applications. It enables users to create applications from data that can be used across mobile, tablet, and web platforms. It also provides a canvas for users to create applications with a drag-and-drop interface. Power Apps also provides a library of connectors to connect to other services such as Dynamics 365, Office 365, SharePoint, and more.'}
```

Comment: What version of langchain are you using? and where are you importing all of these classes / modules from?

Comment: @LoganAnderson I am using langchain =0.0.249
please help me how can i send output parser directly to Chain to get output warning free

Comment: Maybe try updating to 0.0.250? Looks like it contains some bug fixes.

Comment: @LoganAnderson this is still throw error how can i pass output parser in my chain